# Linking a css file removes background

Tags: html, css, file, hyperlink, include

**This Question Has Been Answered:
Okay I found the solution. The problem was the css document still contained the  html tags. Thank you for everyone who helped.**

I have been using css to design a site. The site works perfect when the css is directly in the HTML code. However, if I save the css in an external file in the same directory as the html file and include it using the  tag, it keeps the layout but the background goes away. The background is set to an image. Below is my css code.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url('http://www.thepeepinghole.tk/pics/stone.jpg');
color: white;
}
#menubar {
position: relative;
width: 75%;
height: 60px;
}
#menubar svg {
margin: 0px;
width:100%;
}
#menubar h3 {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 10px;
}
#top {
height: 150px;
width: 75%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
#top img {
position: absolute;
left: 11%;
top: -2%;
width: 266px;
height: 200px;
width: auto;
z-index: 2;
}
#top img.mirror {
position: absolute;
left: 69%;
top: -2%;
width: 266px;
height: 200px;
width: auto;
z-index: 2;
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
transform: scaleX(-1);
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
#top h2 {
position: relative;
top: 30%;
}
#top h1 {
position: relative;
top: 30%;
}
#menubar a {
color: white;
}
#menubar img {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 85%;
float: right;
}
#content {
width: 75%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
</style>
```

I'm including it in the head of my html with this code:

```
<rel link="StyleSheet" href="http://thepeepinghole.tk/mainpage.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: The web inspector should be helpful in showing the hierarchy of styles.

Comment: Are you linking any other CSS files? One of them may be overriding this.

Comment: @Barmar yup, that may be the problem :D

Comment: In the case that EinerS answer doesn't work, can you link any files?

Comment: There are no other css files only that one. Maybe I am not linking it right. If someone could provide an example it may help.

Comment: I edited the post to include what html code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your syntax is the problem:
Should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://thepeepinghole.tk/mainpage.css" type="text/css">
```

not

```
<rel link="stylesheet"...>
```

Comment: Thanks this did help towards the final solution

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainpage.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are another css rule that override the css rules that are written in the external file.

Example:

```
<rel link="StyleSheet" src="file.css" media="all" type="text/css"
 />
<style>
.background{
//if here is another css rule with the same class or id, this will override the one that is in the external file.
}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh ok I understand but when I try and use the external file I don't have any other style's in my html.

Comment: if you are using chrome, press f12 to open the console and see if the file is being found.